# tar -rvf not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to append a .txt file to my already created .tar archive file. But the following error is showing up:

```
    tar -rvf kits.tar example.txt
    tar: This does not look like a tar archive
    tar: Skipping to next header
    tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers
    example.txt
    tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Kindly explain this

Comment: Are you sure this is a tar archive and not a compressed one? What does `file kits.tar` say?

Comment: You sure it's not compressed? what does file kits.tar report? it is possible that older versions of tar would report this error instead of the more sensible 'cannot update a compressed archive'

Comment: I'm not seeing a programming question here.

Comment: @Nikos : u might be right, when i do :
        
        `tar -xzvf kits.tar`

I see this:

            `gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
            tar: Child returned status 2
            tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors`

Comment: Can you rename it to `kits.tar.gz` or `kits.tgz` and try again your `tar xzvf kits.txt example.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a compressed tar archive with the wrong extension (it should be .tar.gz).

This can happen when you download a tar.gz (or tar.bz2) file, as some browsers try to be smart and save it as a .tar without actually decompressing it, or don't decompress it correctly.